# How is it possible for JVM to run generated machine code from a Java application via JIT?

Tags: java, jvm

How is it possible that JVM compiles bytecode into native code dynamically and then executes it? I can imagine that it is possible to write data values into memory but if I remember correctly, a program can't write to the memory that contains instructions (otherwise viruses could use this feature and proliferate quickly).

Comment: Are you asking how you can run machine code from Java or how the JVM does?

Comment: Viruses do use that feature to proliferate quickly.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a program can't write to the memory that contains instructions" ? If a memory block is already used, then the program moves to an empty space

Comment: It is certainly possible to write to the memory that contains the machine instructions, it's just that the feature is disabled by default to protect against bad input. All you need to enable it is a call to `mprotect` (on Linux at least). Being able to alter its own code doesn't inherently allow a virus to be more dangerous than it would be otherwise.

Comment: To Jeremiah Willcock:I was referring to how JVM compiles bytecode to native instructions and then executes them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very few architectures implement the level of memory protection (only the OS has write access to memory areas containing code) you're talking about, the ones where Java uses a JIT definitely don't.

And viruses do use this feature and even more to proliferate quickly. But when you think about it, there's nothing inherently dangerous in a process modifying its own code. It isn't any more dangerous than being able to write to a file and then load a library.

Comment: Except when we consider that most libraries are debugged, while a self-modifying process is famously NOT debugged in early days :-)

Comment: @Pete Wilson What I meant was that a process can write the code into a file then ask the OS to load it as a dynamic library. The effect would be the same as self-modifying code from a security perspective.

Comment: Thanks Pete Wilson for a valid point on the statement about viruses.

Comment: In processes that don't use JIT, most pages have either write or exec premission, but not both.  Bring this down to zero pages with write+exec at any given moment is a Good Thing for security: if a buffer overflow lets an attacker put arbitrary data into memory, not being able to execute it as code (if they also gain control of the program counter, e.g. by overwriting a return address on the stack) may stop them from doing more than crashing your program.  But finding usable blocks of code that already exist is a thing, see return-to-libc attacks.

Answer (score 4):

Normally, you can't write to the section of memory that contains code directly, but there are ways to override that.  For JITs, often what is done is to have some read-write data space on the heap and then use an operation such as `mprotect` to make it executable.

Answer (score 3):

OSes do provide facilities to allocate "executable" memory.  The JVM needs to allocate the target memory in a different way than standard malloc() when generating JITed code.

For example, on Windows, use [VirtualAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with [PAGE_EXECUTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366786%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Similar functions exist in Linux, AIX, etc...